# How to display a line for every python cell boundary in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when working with python files, if we type `#%%` it creates a cell separation.  When the cursor is within a cell, the editor displays a thick line for the top boundary and a thin line for the bottom boundary (of the current cell only).  How can I change the style so that a line is always displayed for every cell boundary (like in the Spyder editor)?

**Edit:**
I found these settings but they only apply to the interactive window and not the editor:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "notebook.cellBorderColor": "#ff0000",
        "notebook.cellToolbarSeparator": "#00ff00"
    }
```

I am expecting to find a way of showing lines at the red arrows below:
[image: Missing Python cell delimiter lines]

I have seen screenshots showing such lines but I can't find how.

**Edit 2:** Is there a way to customize the style/appearance of every inserted line showing the clickable commands `Run Cell | Run Above | Debug Cell` ?

Comment: Sorry, but It looks impossible.

Comment: It does not seem impossible, since I can see them in this screenshot (for cells #1 and #4) https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30958850/60267591-7be2c200-98e2-11e9-951d-d1796b1b35a0.png

Comment: I do not see any lines at #4. In my opinion it seems to be a feature, which is not available.

Comment: @MiniMik, zoom in and look closely, there is a thin dark grey line at #4 and #1 in this screenshot: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30958850/60267591-7be2c200-98e2-11e9-951d-d1796b1b35a0.png

Comment: I've seen that, but I'm conviced, thats from the box of the inserted 'line' with the commands.

Comment: @MiniMik, yes that would do. I just want them to show in my editor, and if possible, brighter.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:  [extension-visualstudio](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook)

maybe we need to checkout [vscode-python] (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python)： package.nls.json stores a lot of dicts, but i can't find Run Cell | Run Above | Debug Cell too..

Answer (score 0):

As a possible hack, you can extend the cell commands.

The setting for that is called "Jupyter: Code Lenses".
I set mine to:

```
"jupyter.runcell, jupyter.runallcellsabove, jupyter.debugcell, 
 jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell,
 jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell, 
 jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell, jupyter.debugcell"
```

[long cell command list to mimic a cell border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAoha.png)

Answer (score -1):

**Jupyter** is a good choice for you which has separate code cells.

Create jupyter notebook from command palette then install required module `ipykernal`, you can run python code cell in it. Reference: [Jupyter Notebook in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment)

Comment: Sorry, I know Jupyter and other editors exists, but my question is specific to VS Code.